# Read dat in R with separate variables instead of 1 single variable

Tags: r

I try to load a dat file into R with 4 separate variables, but the read.table/read.delim function returns to 1 single variable by connecting the 4 with a colon.

Cam someone help?

```
examdata < read.delim('/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/GSE/EDU 767/Assignment /DataSet/Exam Anxiety.dat', header=TRUE, 
                     sep=",")
```

[image]

Comment: What does the raw test file actually look like? Can you show the first few lines? You probably just specified the wrong separator.

Comment: I did try sep= " " and it is still the problem. It returns to 1 variable with 103 observations.

Comment: The separator is clearly not a comma. It doesn't look like a tab separated file, but try both sep="\t" and sep= " ".

Comment: Hi! Yes, "\t" works. How could I identify whether its a comma separator or " " or "\t"?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of sep = "," just do " ". It is actually"(space bar)".

Comment: As comments to OP's question make clear, your answer makes an assumption that is incorrect.  Please correct your post to make it relevant and supply a complete working solution.  Since qw ask those asking questions to provide a MRE, this is only fair.